# How use jQuery's contains() to find special char ( and )

Tags: jquery, contains

contains() is used to find a string / text.

But my text includes `(` and `)`. Like `bank of america(west)`

And it does not work.

Comment: This shouldn't be a jQuery question, it should be a regular expressions question.

Comment: Please show us your full statement.

Comment: @Khoa Of GOd: Can we please haz the codez?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood meaning of .contains()

```
jQuery.contains(document.documentElement, document.body); // true
jQuery.contains(document.body, document.documentElement); // false
```

> Description: Check to see if a DOM element is within another DOM element.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/

You probably mean :contains

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/462b6/5

```
<div id="element">bank of america (test) here</div>

<script>
$(function(){
   $("#element:contains('bank of america (test)')").css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
</script>
```

works

Comment: I think OP is referring to the selector. http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: @PeeHaa: yes, I gave him example, read my last line `You probably mean :contains

`

Answer (score 0):

.Contains() finds DOM elements, not text.  If you want to find if text is within a string or not, the simplest way is to use .indexOf().

e.g.

```
'this is a test'.indexOf('is a');
```

returns 5, the position of the first instance of the text in the string.  If the text was not matched it would return -1. Therefore to check if the text is contained within the string you just do:

```
if(theString.indexOf(searchText) > -1) {
  ...
}
```